# How to create a scroll bounce effect when using jquery smooth scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have just added smooth scrolling into my website but now i want it to get to where it's scrolling to then have a bounce effect, any ideas?

This is my code right now for the smooth scrolling ...

```
    $('a[href^="#"]').on("click", function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);

    // Scroll
    $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 2000, 'swing', function() {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });

});
```